# print c_el ошибка expected an indented block

Tags: python, excel

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import xlrd

rb = xlrd.open_workbook("C:/Таблица.xlsx", formatting_info=True)

sheet= rb.sheet_by_index(0)

for rownum in range(sheet.nrows):row = sheet.row_values(rownum)

for c_el in row:

print c_el
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас есть ошибки с форматированием кода. Содержимое циклов принято отделять табуляцией на следующей строке, изображая вложенность, а у вас код написан сразу после ":"

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import xlrd

rb = xlrd.open_workbook("C:/Таблица.xlsx", formatting_info=True)

sheet = rb.sheet_by_index(0)

for rownum in range(sheet.nrows):
    row = sheet.row_values(rownum)

for c_el in row:
    print c_el
```